# Better method of a timer in Python

Tags: python, timer

I am currently using:

```
class RepeatedTimer(object):
    def __init__(self, interval, function, *args, **kwargs):
        self._timer = None
        self.interval = interval
        self.function = function
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.is_running = False
        self.start()

    def _run(self):
        self.is_running = False
        self.start()
        self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)

    def start(self):
        if not self.is_running:
            self._timer = Timer(self.interval, self._run)
            self._timer.start()
            self.is_running = True

    def stop(self):
        self._timer.cancel()
        self.is_running = False
```

to run a section of code every 24 hours, however, this looks messy and I think it can be simplified.

I want to run a function every 24 hours.  Is there a simpler and cleaner method?

Comment: `is_running` should be set Fals AFTER calling the function, not BEFORE. Right?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this in Python, rather than using [`cron`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/cron) (or the [Windows Task Scheduler](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726974.aspx)) which are tools designed for just this purpose?

Comment: What is the definition of class Timer?

Answer (score 4):

If the goal is to run a task at the same time each day, it is better
to capture the value of the real-time clock, because using successive 24 
hour intervals can give you a "time creep".  Something along these lines 
would work fine (you'd probably put this in a separate thread):

```
import time

def time_of_day:
     return time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

target_time = "18:00:00"

while True:
    while time_of_day() != target_time:
         time.sleep(.1)
    call_function()
    while time_of_day() == target_time:
         time.sleep(.1)
```

Comment: Oops.  The original version used up cpu time.  Corrected.